# Multiple jobs are processing with one worker

Tags: php, rabbitmq, queue, laravel-5.1

I have an app built on laravel 5.1 which is using RabbitMQ for job processing. The worker command is as follows:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=[queue-name] --daemon --tries=5
```

The issue which I am experiencing is that multiple jobs are getting processed at the same time even though I have only one worker for the queue. How and why is this happening? I have a table which tracks the status of the jobs and as per the table, the number of parallel processing jobs sometimes increase to 8 or 9. With one worker, this count is strange.

**Note:**

- My application has 3500-4000 jobs for processing daily
- The jobs are time consuming so dont know if this has something to do with the process timeout

Comment: How you run worker command? using `supervisor` ?

Comment: No they are setup using systemd